# How to compare multiple choice with single choice?

Tags: surveys, choices

I have a long-running survey with one question where participants are forced to select a single choice. Now we are discussing about changing this question to multiple selection.
Is there a way to compare the numbers before and after?

Answer (score 1):

A multiple choice answer loses the attribute of *preference*.

When I choose a single option, I eventually choose the one I *prefer*, even if some other options seem close.
When I choose multiple answers, any one of them is a *possibility*, even if remote.

It makes quite a difference in the survey. I would regard it as a different question, unless you want to change the wording to account for some preference.

Hard to say more without specific details, but this is my general view.